# TinyMCE insertHTML modifies some HTML tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have some content in tinymce 6 editor. I moved the cursor and placed it inside the content and executed

```
tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent(`<span class='dummy'>
                        <div><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">This Text is BOLD</span></div>
                        <div><span style="font-style:italic;">This text is Italic</span></div>
                        <div><span style="text-decoration:underline;">This Text is&#160; Underlined</span></div>
                      </span>`, {format: 'html'});
```

When I execute this the `div` elements are getting removed.

I can see the content inside the `BeforeSetContent` event. But on the `SetContent` event the content is getting modified and the div are removed. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour ?

I tried adding

```
valid_children: '+div[span], +span[div]'
```

in the editor config.

I am expecting the html content to be added into the tinymce 6 editor without modifying the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is to remove certain elements, such as `<div>`, when they are inserted using the `insertContent` method.
But you can override this behavior by customizing the editor's schema and adding a rule to allow the `<div>` element:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#your-selector',
  // other configurations...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('BeforeSetContent', function (e) {
      // Allow the <div> element in the content
      e.content = e.content.replace(/<div>/g, '<div data-mce-bogus="1">');
    });
  },
  valid_elements: 'div[*]' // Allow all attributes on <div> elements
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me correctly
https://jsfiddle.net/athulms/3467b80q/9

Click on the Insert content button in the jsfiddle. You can see all the content are added in single line, but expected to be in three different lines are there are three outer `div` for each `span` element

Comment: any idea on why its not working in the fiddle ? @iamdlm

Comment: Apparently `<span>` elements are being rendered in the same line. If you use `<div>` only it seems to work fine. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7du5f4bz/).